# node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js: .plugins[0] must be a string

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to upgrade my expo version from `SDK 48` to `SDK 50` because already deprecated. So when I followed all the step from here `https://expo.dev/changelog/2024/01-18-sdk-50` ,i got nothing error including `npx expo-doctor@latest` command. But then when I want to run the app using command `npx expo start --clear` i got this error

> error: node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js: .plugins[0] must be a string, object, function

[image: upgrade command]

[image: error]

I also already tried to delete node_modules and package-lock.json but i still got the same error. If it is because of dependencies, how do i know which one are the issue?

```json
{
    "name": "GoldNow",
    "version": "2.0.2",
    "dependencies": {
        "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
        "@kichiyaki/react-native-barcode-generator": "^0.6.7",
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
        "@react-native-community/cli": "^10.2.0",
        "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.6.1",
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
        "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.6.1",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
        "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.0.0",
        "expo": "~50.0.5",
        "expo-asset": "~9.0.2",
        "expo-dev-client": "~3.3.8",
        "expo-document-picker": "~11.10.1",
        "expo-file-system": "~16.0.5",
        "expo-font": "~11.10.2",
        "expo-image-picker": "~14.7.1",
        "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.7.1",
        "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.4",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
        "install": "^0.13.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "patch-package": "^6.5.1",
        "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.73.2",
        "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
        "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
        "react-native-countdown": "^0.0.3",
        "react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.1",
        "react-native-countdown-timer-hooks": "^1.0.3",
        "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
        "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
        "react-native-normalize": "^1.0.1",
        "react-native-otp-inputs": "^7.4.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
        "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
        "react-native-searchable-dropdown": "^1.1.3",
        "react-native-smooth-pincode-input": "^1.0.9",
        "react-native-svg": "14.1.0",
        "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
        "react-native-webview": "13.6.4",
        "react-native-wizard": "^2.1.1",
        "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
        "redux": "^4.2.1",
        "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
        "typescript": "^5.1.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "patch-package"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue where the package.json clearing didn't help either.
The solution ended up being related to a clash with the react-native version I had configured (and some sub libraries like metro-config.)

Fixed it with a simple npm install react-native@latest.

I personally also did an upgrade on npm install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@latest but that's likely project dependant.

Hope this helps.